# How to two joins in linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I trying to write sql query to linq:

**Query:**

```
select s.s_name, sub.state, sub.to, sub.evaluation, sub.task_id
from submit_task sub
join student s on s.id=sub.student_id
join task t on t.id=sub.task_id
where t.t_name = "bbbb";
```

**Linq:**

```
var subTask = (from sub in ado.submit_task
               join s in ado.student on sub.student_id equals s.id
               join t in ado.task on sub.task_id equals t.id
               where t.t_name == listView3.SelectedItems[0].Text
               select new { s.s_name, sub.state, sub.to, 
                            sub.evaluation, sub.task_id });
```

but this not working. When I try dubugg, nothing's happened, with no error or result. Do you see some mistake ??

thankk you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var text = listView3.SelectedItems[0].Text;

var subTask = (from sub in ado.submit_task
  join s in ado.student on sub.student_id equals s.id
  join t in ado.task on sub.task_id equals t.id
  where t.t_name == text
  select new { s.s_name, sub.state, sub.to, sub.evaluation, sub.task_id });
```